# Is there a way to set up my Azure Log Interactive retention only for 7 Days?

Tags: azure, logging, analytics, interactive, retention

Is there a way to set up my Azure Log Interactive retention only for 7 Days ? It is set to 30 Days by default and from the Azure portal option is not there.

We are using the Log analytics but we want the data to be stored only for 7 Days. Not for 30 Days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tables with   `Table plan` -  `Analytics`  has Interactive retention set to 30 days by default.

[image]

- I can see an option to change the `Table plan` for few tables.
  Ex:  AppTraces, AzureDiagnostics,ContainerLog,

[image]

- I have changed the `Table Plan` to `Basic`, I can see the option `Interactive retention` has changed to 8 days and`Total retention period` has an option `Same as interactive retention(8 days)`.

[image]

- Change the Total retention period to `Same as interactive retention (8 days)` and Save.
- As per my observation `Azure Log Interactive retention` can be changed but only for few tables as mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Harshitha. I have found a CLI . we can change for all the tables if needed.

Comment: az monitor log-analytics workspace table update --subscription "TESTSUB" --resource-group DefaultResourceGroup-EUS  --workspace-name DefaultWorkspace-abcfrg-ab5d-4dff16-ad3b-216516sdfda-EUS--name AzureMetrics --